# angular-firebase get currentUser posts

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am developing an angular-firebase ionic app but getting an issue to get current user posts from firebase. All I need is to get current user posts

Here the code:

```
postss: any;
constructor(

private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
) {
this.postss = this.afDB.list('users/posts').valueChanges();

this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {

      }
```

Here the HTML

```
<ion-list no-lines>
<ion-card  *ngFor="let post of posts ">
<li><ul>{{post}} </ul></li>
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: am getting all users posts not current user @frankVanPuffelen

Comment: In order for us to efficiently help you with that, update your question to include a snippet of the JSON under `users` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: i added a photo

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `this.postss = this.afDB.list('users/posts').valueChanges();`, do
`this.postss = this.afDB.list('users/posts/' + user.uid).valueChanges();`. Obviously, the order of operation as posted in your question might need to be modified so that you  get the currentUser.uid before defining your `thi.afDB.list` statement.

Comment: i was try it before but i got this error  :Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "users/posts/[object Object]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the structure of your database but using 'list' just by itself will return all objects located in that path.

You can do a query and specify what objects you want to pull by doing something like this:

```
    this.fireDB.list('users/posts', ref => ref.orderByChild('user_id').equalTo('123')).snapshotChanges().subscribe(res=> {

    res.forEach(doc =>

    this.posts.push(doc.payload.val());

    console.log(doc.payload.val()); //This will show you the values of each post returned.
    console.log(doc.key); //This will show you the ID of the object entry in the database

    });

});
```

The above query for example, will return all objects in the database under users/posts created by user_id = 123

You can read more about angularfire2 [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs/rtdb)

Comment: all i need is current user posts coz my code show all users posts

Comment: Yes, the code I just posted will do that. Change the 'user_id' to whatever field name you put in your database and change the '123' to the desired user you want to retrieve posts for. It can be a variable. I don't know how your database is setup so you may have to change some things around.

Comment: maybe your code is ok but my app got multy users and they post posts to firebase and your code show nothing , all i need is userId somewhere in my angular code i had 2 years now with no solution :(

Comment: The code will narrow down the results to the user you specify. Read more about [querying lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md)

Comment: am crying now , coz i road all angular Doc but nothing i get